# App not retrieving data from Firebase database shows blank screen

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

when user places its order then a table requests gets automatically created on firebase and within that table it contains name, phone no, address. Now in another activity I want to view orders placed and want to retrieve data in recycler view but app is showing blank screen. Here is my java code.

```
public class OrderStatus extends AppCompatActivity {

public RecyclerView recyclerView;
public RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request,OrderViewHolder> adapter;
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference requests;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_status);
    //firebase
    database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    requests=database.getReference("Requests");

    recyclerView= (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.listOrders);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    loadOrders();


}

private void loadOrders() {


    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request, OrderViewHolder>(
            Request.class,
            R.layout.order_layout,
            OrderViewHolder.class,
            requests.orderByChild("phone")
            .equalTo("phone")
    ) {



        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(OrderViewHolder viewHolder, Request model, int position) {
            viewHolder.txtOrderId.setText(adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
            viewHolder.txtOrderStatus.setText(convertCodeToStatus(model.getStatus()));
            viewHolder.txtOrderAddress.setText(model.getAddress());
            viewHolder.txtOrderPhone.setText(model.getPhone());

        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private String convertCodeToStatus(String status) {
    if (status.equals("0"))
        return "placed";
    else if (status.equals("1"))
        return "On my way";
    else
        return "Shipped";
}
```

}

Comment: did you override the onCreateViewHolder() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing a parameter in the method load orders so you try this it worked for me
    private void loadOrders() {

```
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request, OrderViewHolder>(
        Request.class,
        R.layout.order_layout,
        OrderViewHolder.class,
        requests.orderByChild("phone")

)
```